# Spring Data Redis has strange result

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis

I started using spring data redis in my project for temporary storing some data. Redis is new for me, I've never worked something similar to redis before (Key-Value). 
So, traditionally I created repository via extending `CrudRepository` and my @RedisHash is:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@RedisHash(value = "employee", timeToLive = 100)
public class RedisEmployee implements Serializable {


    @Id
    private String id;
    @Indexed
    private Long employeeId;
    private String fullName;
    @Indexed
    private String date;
    @Indexed
    private String companyName;
    private String phone;
}
```

So it works fine but I noticed something strange for me, it's result when 
I watch GUI. 
This is all data when I `save with CrudRepository` only one "entity"

[image]

So, Look how much rows, I just save 1 @RedisHash value, it could be because of @Indexed annotation but anyway it looks very strange for me.

P.S. 
I noticed that without @Indexed it's impossible to find anything, for example:

```
@Repository
public interface RedisEmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<RedisEmployee, String> {

    RedisEmployee findByDateAndCompanyNameAndEmployeeId(String date, String companyName, Long employeeId);
}
```

so, `findByDateAndCompanyNameAndEmployeeId` will not return result if I don't have all fields @Indexed. Can't understand it is proper or not.

Comment: Redis is an in-memory cache service. Spring Data Redis is a framework that utilizes Redis to provide quick results and avoid regular Hits. In a custom Redis Service Implementation, you can use your own key-value store but since this is a framework, they form the keys and store data internally based on Annotations. See this [example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/master/redis/repositories/README.md) , you will understand it better.

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya Yes, I got it. Could you see at the result of save operation of CrudRepository (Redis), I think it's a little bit a lot of useless information or maybe it should work like this? I just want to be sure that everything should work like this. In my project I successfully implemented and it works fine but anyway maybe I miss something. Thanks.